# What's the point of not being able to re-upvote a comment?

Tags: discussion, voting, comments

Why can't you re-upvote a comment that you upvoted and then un-upvoted? You can upvote and un-upvote questions as many times as you want (which I assume is because question edits aren't time-sensitive, so questions can change dramatically while comments are less likely to do so). It just seems like a weird limitation to me.

Comment: Makes you think long and hard about whether or not the comment you've upvoted is worth a flag.  That, and comments are second-class citizens, and if there is a serious problem with a comment, it *should* be flagged.

Comment: @Makoto you can now flag comments that you've upvoted

Comment: @bluet: Well a *year* ago when I wrote the comment, you *couldn't*!  Forgive me for not being with the times. :D

Comment: 3 years later, I'd like an answer to this as well. Seems like an odd thing.

Comment: @kabanus **4 years later** it's _still_ an odd thing